# Python Simple Loop in function

Tags: python, function, loops, program-entry-point

```
for word in sentence.split():

    if word[0] in VOWELS:
        pig_latin = word + "ay"

    else:
        pig_latin = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"

    return pig_latin
```

How do I make it so that the return prints the whole sentence in the main, not just the one word?

Comment: Please show the entire function.

Comment: For fun: If you just change that `return` to `yield`, you can write `for ordway in pig_latinize(sentence): print(ordway)` and it will get all the words. See [Iterators](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) and the following section on Generators in the tutorial. That's probably not what you're asking for… but hopefully you will be soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to *build* the whole sentence in some way. For example, you can build up a list of words:

```
pig_words = []

for word in sentence.split():
    if word[0] in VOWELS:
        pig_latin = word + "ay"
    else:
        pig_latin = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
    pig_words.append(pig_latin)

return pig_words
```

If you want to turn it back into a sentence, the opposite of `split` is `join`, so just change the last line to:

```
return ' '.join(pig_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the values to a list and remove the return statement from the loop, so that it will return the list after the for loops has finished iterating.

```
words = []
for word in sentence.split():
    if word[0] in VOWELS:
        pig_latin = word + "ay"
    else:
        pig_latin = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"

    words.append(pig_latin)

return words
```

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is executed on the first pass though your for loop. Even if you un-indented the return statement to run at the conclusion, you would then only have the last translated word in the pig_latin variable.

To translate the whole sentence, you should only return after the entire for loop runs to completion, saving the accumulated list of translated words.

```
entensesay = []
for word in sentence.split():
    if word[0] in VOWELS:
        entensesay.append(word + "ay")
    else:
        entensesay.append(word[1:] + word[0] + "ay")
return ' '.join(entensesay)
```

It is also good habit to avoid doing string concatenation in loops in Python. List append method is more efficient, and then use ' '.join() to produce the final concatenated string.

Comment: The note about string append being slow is really out of date; the quadratic string concatenation behavior was fixed in Python 2.4, almost a decade ago, and yet people are still repeating it today…